# Casper/Phantomjs unable to retrieve highest resolution src image

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to make a basic Instagram web scraper, both art inspiration pictures and just generally trying to boost my knowledge and experience programming.

Currently the issue that I am having is that Casper/Phantomjs can't detect higher res images from the srcset, and I can't figure out a way around this. Instagram has their srcsets provide 640x640, 750x750, and 1080x1080 images. I would obviously like to retrieve the 1080, but it seems to be undetectable by any method I've tried so far. Setting the viewport larger does nothing, and I can't retrieve the entire source set through just getting the HTML and splitting it where I need it. And as far as I can tell, there is no other way to retrieve said image than to get it from this srcset.

### Edit

As I was asked for more details, here I go. This is the code I used to get the attributes from the page:

```
function getImages() {
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('._2di5p');
return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
    return e.getAttribute('src');
});
}
```

Then I do the standard:

```
casper.waitForSelector('div._4rbun', function() {
  this.echo('...found selector ...try getting image srcs now...');
    imagesArray = this.evaluate(getImages);
    imagesArray.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
```

However, all that is returned is the lowest resolution of the srcset. Using this url, for example, (https://www.instagram.com/p/BhWS4csAIPS/?taken-by=kasabianofficial) all that is returned is `https://instagram.flcy1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b282bb23f82318697f0b9b85279ab32e/5B5CE6F2/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/29740443_908390472665088_4690461645690896384_n.jpg`, which is the lowest resolution (640x640) image in the srcset. Ideally, I'd like to retrieve the `https://instagram.flcy1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d20f803e1cb06e394ac91383fd9a462/5B5C9093/t51.2885-15/e35/29740443_908390472665088_4690461645690896384_n.jpg` which is the 1080x1080 image in the srcset. But I can't. There's no way to get that item as far as I can tell. It's completely hidden.

Comment: `can't retrieve the entire source set through just getting the HTML and splitting it` What have you tried? Please edit the question to show it.

Comment: @Vaviloff I mean that while you or I can open an element inspector to see all items in a srcset, casper/phantom can't. They can only see the lowest resolution item, as there is no way to currently fix the display pixel ratio. Intagram would detect the headless browser as only capable of handling the lowest resolution items, so they coudn't even see the entire srcset. Only the low res option. I did find a way around this for Instagram, but it won't work everywhere.

Comment: It is considered good practice here to show a minimal working example of your code. It could be a matter of a *single typo* preventing your script from working but we couldn't help because you show nothing.

Comment: For example: `Intagram would detect the headless browser` But have you tried to not let it detect the headlessness?

Comment: @vaviloff I've certainly tried. Setting viewportSize changes absolutely nothing. And as for the comment about working code, there's not much I can show. The script works just fine, but search by image tags, then narrowing it down, returns a single src item, and it is the lowest res link of the srcset.

Comment: look at another way to find the URL in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: So my solution was to use slimerjs. If I run the js file through "casperjs --engine=slimerjs fileName.js", I can retrieve srcsets in full. So if I say use this code:

```
function getImgSrc() {
  var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("._2di5p");
  return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
      return e.getAttribute("srcset");
  });
}
```

on this url (https://www.instagram.com/p/BhWS4csAIPS/?taken-by=kasabianofficial) I will get (https://instagram.flcy1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b282bb23f82318697f0b9b85279ab32e/5B5CE6F2/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/29740443_908390472665088_4690461645690896384_n.jpg 640w,https://instagram.flcy1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b4eebf94247af02c63d20320f6535ab4/5B6258DF/t51.2885-15/s750x750/sh0.08/e35/29740443_908390472665088_4690461645690896384_n.jpg 750w,https://instagram.flcy1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d20f803e1cb06e394ac91383fd9a462/5B5C9093/t51.2885-15/e35/29740443_908390472665088_4690461645690896384_n.jpg 1080w) as the result.

This is what I wanted as it means I can scrape those 1080 images. Sorry for this messy page, but I wanted to leave my trail of steps to any of those who might be trying like me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it in Instagram's case. Instagram puts the source picture in a meta tag within the head. So, using the code I'll paste below, you can call all of the meta tags and then sort out which one is the source picture by checking if "og:image" is retrieved.

```
function getImages() {
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('meta[content]');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(scripts, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('property') + " " + e.getAttribute('content');
    });
}
```

And this is the way to sort the meta tags into only having the original image in its native resolution.

```
this.echo('...found selector ...try getting image srcs now...');
imagesArray = this.evaluate(getImages);
imagesArray.forEach(function (item) {
    if (typeof item == "string" && item.indexOf('og:image') > -1) {
```

Edit: Unfortunately this only works for single image posts on Instagram (the site I'm trying to scrape) so this unfortunately does me no goo. The values within the meta tags don't change even if you load the next image in the post. I'm leaving this up though in case anyone else could use it, but it's not ideal for my own use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed PhantomJS doesn't seem to support `srcset`, its Webkit engine is very old.

But to be fair, all the metadata related to the page is out in the open in the HTML as JSON in `window._sharedData` variable.

If you want to use a headless browser (and not parse it with any server-side language) you can do this:

```
var imgUrl = page.evaluate(function(){
    return window._sharedData.entry_data.PostPage[0].graphql.shortcode_media.display_resources[2].src;
});
```

> https://instagram.fhen2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d20f803e1cb06e394ac91383fd9a462/5B5C9093/t51.2885-15/e35/29740443_908390472665088_4690461645690896384_n.jpg

Comment: Sorry, this is a way late response and I'm not doing this so much to comment, as to provide a good string of resources for anyone else who comes looking. I believe, if I am interpreting your code correctly, that imgUrl just gets the image from the meta data. I had a similar, though less elegant, way of getting the same data above. The issue is that with Instagram, meta data changes only on different posts. So 1 post could have 10 images, and you can only use the meta data to retrieve the first. Still, I ended up finding a different solution thanks to you. Sorry for no upvotes, I'm not allowed.

Comment: No, this code gets imgUrl from internal data of the web page. If one wishes they can work with array containing all the data about the post including all resolutions of the image.